# Find the density function for a random variable that measures the time of a video.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, density-function

I hope can give me a hint for this exercise.

On a new digital platform such as youtube, each user posts videos of up to 30 seconds. The platform created a remuneration system (by video) that is based on the total viewing time in the first week of publication (of users other than the author of the video). If, for example, a 30-second video is viewed exactly 10 times in full during the first week of publication, the total time would be 300 seconds. If, on the other hand, such a video is viewed only once and halfway through the first week, the total viewing time would be 15 seconds. Let's say that a new video is published and let T be the random variable which represents its total viewing time (in the first week of publication).

(i) Does it make sense to assume that T is a continuous random variable?Justify your answer

**Ans:** According to the problem, T is the total time, since there are an infinite number of possible times that can be taken it is continous.

(ii) Assuming that T is continuous, choose a set of values ​​that the random variable T should assume??

**Ans:** That depends on the times of views, so it can take $0\leq T<\infty$

(iii) Propose a density function for T that is compatible with the answer above.

This confusses me because T depends in the time of view, so it will be something like $T(X)$, but it shouldn't be sometinhg like $f(T)$?

(iv) Given the density function that fits with the item (iii), what is the probability that the total video viewing time (in the first week) is less than 60 seconds?

If I understand item (iii) I think can do item(iv)

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be not additional information, so (iii) may be any probability density function of your choice which is consistent with (ii).  It might be wise to choose one which allows you to answer (iv) easily

Comment: Answering "yes" to (i) would suggest that the probability of no views at all is $0$ - which may be sensible if the uploader always checks the upload has worked and plays, but otherwise perhaps less so

Answer (score 1):

The question is open ended, but here are some initial thoughts:

1. We say $T$ is a *continuous* random variable when its *image* is uncountably infinite.  Since $T$ represents time, it seems reasonable to assume it is continuous. Note that this does not necessarily imply $T$ is *absolutely continuous*, which means it has a density (and hence assigns mass zero to any particular time). Not sure if you have learnt of this distinction as yet, but it is a technicality.
2. A lower bound is zero, but it is not clear that the upper bound should be infinite. There are only 604,800 seconds in a week---multiply that by the number of possible distinct viewers. Nonetheless, we can choose $T\in [0,\infty)$ for modeling simplicity.
3. Assuming $T$ is absolutely continuous, choose a density that best represents the data.  There are nonparametric ways to do this (e.g. kernel density estimation), but it looks like you want a parametric approach here. Any density with a support of $[0,\infty)$, e.g. a chi-squared distribution, is then technically feasible so long as you can justify it against the data. The density takes the form $f(t)$ where $f(t)\geq 0\quad\forall t\in [0,\infty)$ and $\int_0^\infty f(t)=1.$
4. $P(T<60)=\int_0^{60} f(t)dt$.